# How to combine multiple heterogenous model forms into one form in Django

Tags: django, forms, model

I'm very confused. I have several models, say A,B,and C which I'd like to combine into a single form. The models are not related by foreign keys. Right now in my template I have one html form and within it I include modelforms for A, B, and C. This works for display but it's ugly when I submit...I'd like to get the models to save automatically the way a single modelform does via subclassing CreateView. It doesn't seem like modelformsets help here. Is this possible in Django??? Thanks

Comment: Why can't you pass 3 ModelForms into 1 template? That's pretty normal way and works fine.

Comment: I can do this but when it comes time to submit then how do I avoid things getting ugly on saving the forms in the view? Is there a way to use CreateView with three model forms? (our shop uses CBVs whenever possible). Because as I understand it CreateView you specify a single modelform...

Comment: I think https://github.com/AndrewIngram/django-extra-views/ is the way to go for you. Specifically `CreateWithInlinesView`.